# Invited to an Interview follow up meeting

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, work-environment, meetings, feedback

I had an Interview with the Infrastructure Development Manager, Development Engineering Team Leader and the Talent Acquisition Manager for the company. They promised to provide feedback the following week which they did.

The email reads "
Following your interview, we have now made our decision on our preferred candidate.  Would we be able to schedule a follow up meeting for 6.30am your time on Thursday 6th July? [Later rescheduled for next week.] You can join the meeting on the link below."

I'm so nervous and anxious at the same time. I don't know what to expect. What could this mean. Am l their preferred candidate or not. If not why they didn't inform me on that email.

Thank you for your help.

---

The meeting was supposed to be yesterday but postponed due to unavailability of the Talent Acquisition Manager who couldn't be available yesterday. So the meeting was rescheduled for next week.

Comment: We can't tell you what they're thinking. But as the meeting was yesterday, you presumably know the answer already...

Comment: Why are asking what to do for an interview that was scheduled for yesterday?

Comment: The meeting was rescheduled for next week due unavailability of the Talent Acquisition Manager.

Comment: It's fine to ask what a meeting is about when they suggest it. They may choose not to tell you but they won't get angry at you for asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Am l their preferred candidate or not?

We don't know.

The standard procedure for declining a candidate these days is a short "thanks, but no thanks" notice or, annoyingly, they just ghost you. So an in-person meeting is typically a good sign,  but you won't know until it happens.

> I'm so nervous and anxious at the same time.

Don't be. Instead prepare yourself for any possibility you can think of. Playing a conversation through your head and preparing a bunch of adequate responses will make you more effective and confident in the meeting.

1. Could be a rejection: in this case just be friendly and thank them for the opportunity and the courtesy of giving a message in person.
2. Could be that they want to hire you. Make sure you prepare yourself for discussions around start date, compensation, benefits, details of the role, job title, time line, next steps, etc.
3. Could be downgrade or sidegrade: They may have chosen a different candidate but want to explore a different role for you in the company. Think about what type of roles you would accept or not, what compensation is you minimum, etc. You can always ask for more time to think about it.

At the very least be prepared for a compensation discussion.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will be prepared for any case. As the meeting was rescheduled for next week

Comment: It's a bit odd to say they've made a decision but call you in (if it's another interview they wouldn't have made a decision; if it's an onboarding meeting they'd presumably tell you you're hired). It does sound as if they might have an alternative position or something they want to discuss with you.

Comment: Okay, l get you. I will just hang in there until the meeting. I will definitely come here to give feedback.

Comment: 3 seems to be the most likely.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think any prospective employer would waste their time calling you in to tell you that you weren't successful.  Because I would do this, I would suggest that

- You are either on the shortlist and they want to ask a few more questions
- Or you have been successful and they want to tell you in person and discuss/sign the contract and discuss some items.

Comment: Or "We've filled that position but we think you'd be great in another slot and we'd like to pitch that to you."